# shiny datatable in landscape orientation

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

I have code as following in shiny

```
DT::renderDataTable({ 
  df()
  , rownames=FALSE
  ,extensions = c('Responsive', 'Buttons')
  , options = list(
    # dom = 'C<"clear">T<"clear">lfrtip'
    # , tableTools=list(sSwfPath = copySWF('www'))
    dom = 'Bfrtip'
    , buttons = c('pageLength'
                  , 'colvis'
                  , 'pdf')
    , orientation ='landscape'
    , lengthMenu = list(c(6, 12, 18, -1), c('6', '12', '18', 'All'))
    , pageLength = 12
    )
  )
}
})
```

I want to download pdf in landscape. How should I do it.

According to following link: https://datatables.net/reference/button/pdf that we can pass orientation as landscape. However, I am not able to do it.

I have tried following:

```
DT::renderDataTable({ 
  df()
  , rownames=FALSE
  ,extensions = c('Responsive', 'Buttons')
  , options = list(
    # dom = 'C<"clear">T<"clear">lfrtip'
    # , tableTools=list(sSwfPath = copySWF('www'))
    dom = 'Bfrtip'
    , buttons = c('pageLength'
                  , 'colvis'
                  , list(extend: 'pdf', orientation='landscape')
    , orientation ='landscape'
    , lengthMenu = list(c(6, 12, 18, -1), c('6', '12', '18', 'All'))
    , pageLength = 12
    )
  )
}
})
```

Answer (score 10):

This works for me. Since you didn't provide the data I used the iris dataset. Not the the pdf is in landscape orientation but the table does not use all the available space, but the behavior is the same as in the [datatables example](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/pdfPage.html). It does not work from RStudio, but it does in the browser (Firefox 49.0)

This is the code:

```
    library(shiny)
    library(DT)

    shinyApp(
            ui = fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')),
            server = function(input, output) {
                    output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
                            datatable(
                                    iris,
                                    rownames = FALSE,
                                    extensions = c('Responsive', 'Buttons'), options = list(
                                            pageLength = 12,
                                            orientation ='landscape',
                                            lengthMenu = list(c(6, 12, 18, -1), c('6', '12', '18', 'All')),
                                            dom = 'Bfrtip',
                                            buttons = 
                                                    list('pageLength', 'colvis', list(
                                                            extend = 'pdf',
                                                            pageSize = 'A4',
                                                            orientation = 'landscape',
                                                            filename = 'tt'


                                                    ))

                                    ))
                    )
            }
    )
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I have to comment on this amazingly excellent response. Thank you kind sir.